# My php's if statement goes through even if the required value is not present

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to create a reservation system that goes from 8AM to 4PM and I've deliberately set my most recent date on the database to: 2016-04-23 17:50:00 which would translate to an hour of 5 and a minute of 50 but somehow even if my if statement only accepts 8,9,10,11,1,2,3 values for an hour, it still manages to enter with an hour of 5.

My code is:

```
$get_recent_date = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT date FROM schedule ORDER BY date desc"));
$get_datetime = new DateTime($get_recent_date['date']);
$date = date_format($get_datetime, 'j'); //numeric date w/o leading zeros
$month = date_format($get_datetime, 'n'); //numeric month w/o leading zeros
$year = date_format($get_datetime, 'Y'); //numeric year w/o leading zeros
$hour = date_format($get_datetime, 'g'); //numeric hour w/o leading zeroes
$minute = date_format($get_datetime, 'i'); //numeric hour w/o leading zeroes

echo "Hour is: "; echo $hour; echo "<br>";
echo "Minute is: "; echo $minute; echo "<br>";

if ($hour == "8" || "9" || "10" || "11" || "1" || "2" || "3")
{
    if($minute == "0" || "00" || "10" || "20" || "30" || "40")
    {
        echo "Minute before adding ten is: "; echo $minute; echo "<br>";
        $minute = $minute + '10';
        echo "New Minute is: "; echo $minute; echo "<br>";
            if($minute == "60")
            {
                echo "Wtf, why did it go here?";
            }
    }

    else if($minute == "50")
    {
        $hour = $hour + '1';
        $minute = "0";

        $date = strtotime($date);
        $hour = strtotime($hour);
        $minute = strtotime($minute);
        echo $date; echo $hour; echo $minute;
        $got_datetime = date_create_from_format('j-n-Y-g-i', "$date-$month-$year-$hour-$minute");
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO schedule (date) VALUES ($got_datetime)");
    }

    else
    {
        echo "Minute is incorrect";
    }

}


else {
    echo "Hour is incorrect";
}
```

I tried troubleshooting it by placing echoes to determine until where my ifs are being penetrated and here's the result:

```
Hour is: 5
Minute is: 50
Minute before adding ten is: 50
New Minute is: 60
Wtf, why did it go here?
```

(I unfortunately can't post a pic since I'm a new user)

Comment: Try this : `if ($hour == "8" || $hour == "9" || $hour == "10" || $hour == "11" || $hour == "1" || $hour == "2" || $hour == "3")`

Comment: Oh it worked, thanks! so I have to compare every possible values one by one with the variable.

Comment: Yes, you have to compare each one.

Comment: You can also create an array with all the values, then check if the value is in the array. `$values = array(1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11); if (in_array($hour, $values) { /* It's there */ }` -- this is easier if you have many variables.

Comment: Oh wow thanks! Now my code is cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($hour == "8" || "9" || "10" || "11" || "1" || "2" || "3")
```

should be

```
if ($hour == "8" || $hour == "9" || $hour == "10" || $hour == "11" || $hour == "1" || $hour == "2" || $hour == "3")
```

And similarly everywhere else.

The string "9" will evaluate as boolean 'true', so ($hour=="8" || "9") is the same as writing ($hour == "8" || true ) - or just "true".

Comment: I see thanks, not only for this but you also answered another question I was about to ask.